# How to conditionally repeat the <tfoot> element?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to repeat the `<tfoot>` element only on select pages?

If yes, how can it be done? Right now, I'm able to repeat on EVERY page, with this:

```
tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
```

How should I change this css if I want the `<tfoot>` to be displayed only on certain specific pages, say, just the even numbered pages or just multiples of 3? Something like that.

Using some javascript would also be helpful, though not the preferred option.

Comment: What do mean by 'selected pages'?

Comment: @aUXcoder, "specific", not "selected". Sorry, for the error.. edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS preprocessor Sass.With Sass you can write CSS based on conditions like if.

I have attached reference link for the same.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

Answer (score 0):

A simple ‘ng-if’ is enough for your requirement here I guess.

```
<tfoot ng-if=“yourCondition”>
     Your code
</tfoot>
```

For even numbered pages yourCondition can be like this,

`ng-if=“!ctrl.pageNumber % 2”`

For multiple of 3

`ng-if=“!ctrl.pageNumber % 3”`

‘%’ is a modulus operator.

Comment: is ".pageNumber" a property of something? and what's control?

Comment: It’s the variable you’re talking about. You should know which page you’re on to apply any sort of condition.

Comment: I get your point... But the thing is is, as I've mentioned in the question, the `display: table-footer-group;` css styling, just makes sure it's displayed in all pages. I'm using this, since I don't know the page numbers. On a sidenote, it's because i'm printing the html as a pdf, and it's the browser that pages the content.